# one to many relationship not showing in admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was making a post system with two models `Post` and `Image`. I want one post to have multiple images

Here is my models

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    images = models.ManyToOneRel(
        field="image", to="Image", field_name="images")


class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    image = models.ImageField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
```

When I checked it in admin the images field is not shown.

[image: admin]

I am not entirely sure how to use ManyToOneRel in django. So far what I understood is I need  my post saved before i can add an image. Is there any other way I can have multiple images for one post

Comment: A `ManyToOneRel` is a `ForeignKey`. You are confusing the "relation" with the field.

Comment: I have a very less experience in django previously i worked with sqlalchemy i can have a foreign key on the child table and make a realtionship on the parent table. In django is it different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only want one relation,in my opinion Foriegn key is better

Just try this:-

```
class Post(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
content = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
image=models.ForeignKey(Image,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)


class Image(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
image = models.ImageField()
```

**Note:- 'Foreign-key itself is a Many-To-One Relation'**

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a relation with a model field. If you want to specify a many-to-one relation, you do that with a `ForeignKey`, not a  <s>`ManyToOneRel`</s>. This should thus look like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    image = models.ForeignKey(to='Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE)!
```

Likely you are however not interested in a many-to-one relation, but in a one-to-many relation (where one post can contain zero, one, or more `Image`s). In that case the `ForeignKey` belongs to the `Image` model, and you thus set this when you create a new `Image` object in the `ModelAdmin`: